# Nokogumbo installation on Mojave 10.14 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, nokogumbo

I am trying to run bundle install after updating the most recent security updates to [Rails](https://twitter.com/rails/status/1105882173784113152) and [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/03/13/ruby-2-6-2-released/), and cannot install the Nokogumbo gem. I get the following error message:

```
An error occurred while installing nokogumbo (1.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogumbo -v '1.5.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried running `gem install nokogumbo -v '1.5.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` and got this:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogumbo:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogumbo-1.5.0/ext/nokogumboc
/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/bin/ruby -I /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20190314-8398-fmosg1.rb extconf.rb
checking for xmlNewDoc() in -lxml2... yes
checking for nokogiri.h in /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/ext/nokogiri... no
checking if the C compiler accepts  -I /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libxml2... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.4.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.9
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Revert-Do-not-URI-escape-in-server-side-includes.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Activating libxml2 2.9.9 (from /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0/libxml2/2.9.9)...
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxslt-1.1.33.

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install
************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-xml2lib
    --without-xml2lib
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.4.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:293:in `verify_file': Downloaded file '/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/ports/archives/libxslt-1.1.33.tar.gz' has wrong hash: expected: 8e36605144409df979cab43d835002f63988f3dc94d5d3537c12796db90e38c8 is: d020ac32fcb0778e2f636fc31ac205f3f00aceec08c61a090fefa30110daaddc (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.4.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:61:in `block in extract'
    from /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.4.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:60:in `each'
    from /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.4.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:60:in `extract'
    from /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mini_portile2-2.4.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:151:in `cook'
    from /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/ext/nokogiri/extconf.rb:365:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
    from /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/ext/nokogiri/extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'
    from /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/ext/nokogiri/extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'
    from /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/ext/nokogiri/extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'
    from /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/ext/nokogiri/extconf.rb:364:in `block in process_recipe'
    from /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/ext/nokogiri/extconf.rb:262:in `tap'
    from /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/ext/nokogiri/extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'
    from /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/ext/nokogiri/extconf.rb:574:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:17:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.6.0-static/nokogumbo-1.5.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogumbo-1.5.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-18/2.6.0-static/nokogumbo-1.5.0/gem_make.out
```

I tried running all the commands that are suggested in that error message as well. With the `bundle config` command, I got a message that said "You are replacing the current global value of build.nokogiri, which is currently "--use-system-libraries=true" etc.

I also tried manually installing nokogumbo 1.4.7, to see if installing an older version of the gem that I could then upgrade might help. No luck. It doesn't make sense as people who have the same set up as me on their machines have been able to install everything fine.

Anyone have any idea what I could do differently? Thanks!

### UPDATE - SOLVED

The fix (*for Mojave 10.14*) is: `gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 --use-system-libraries`

Credit [here](https://github.com/reenhanced/gitreflow/issues/178)

Comment: Please don't answer your question in the question itself. Instead, create an answer and put that information there. SO is more like an online encyclopedia than a chat so we use separate entries for questions and their answers.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue when trying to run bundler in rails. What worked for me was running

```
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle config build.nokogumbo --use-system-libraries
bundle install
```

Setting the `--use-system-libraries` flag for nokogumbo did the trick.